# python mutiprocessing main process waiting for deamon process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand multiprocessing module. Below is my code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
#from time import time
import time

def work(delay):
    p = current_process()
    print p.name, p.pid, p.deamon
    time.sleep(delay)
    print 'Finised deamon work'

def main():
    print 'Starting Main Process'
    p = Process(target=work, args=(2,))
    p.deamon = True
    p.start()
    print 'Exiting Main Process'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Starting Main Process
Exiting Main Process
Process-1 7863 True
Finised deamon work
```

I expect main process to exit before deamon process(sleep for 2 secs). Since main process exits, deamon process should also exit. But output is confusing me.

Expected Output:

```
Starting Main Process
Exiting Main Process
Process-1 7863 True
```

Is my understanding of multiprocessing module wrong?